# Comparison for in SQL row selection not working?

Tags: php, sql

This is the code that is not working:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE text_id > '$last_id'"; //SELECT NEW MESSAGES
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
          //THIS SHOULD NOT BE RUNNING
        }
```

I've verified over and over in phpMyAdmin and the text_id in the table and $last_id are both the integer value '1'. That being said, the condition equates to true every time the code runs.

Am I messing this code up, or is my thinking improper?

Here is entire script:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $alias = $_SESSION['username'];

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = '*';
    $pass = '*';
    $database = 'vethergen_db_accounts';
    $table = 'table_messages';
    $last_id_table = 'table_chat_sync';
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
    mysqli_select_db($connection,$database) or die ("Unable to select database!");

    $last_id_query = "SELECT alias FROM $last_id_table WHERE alias = '$alias'";
    $last_id_result = mysqli_query($connection,$last_id_query);
    $last_id_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($last_id_result);

    if ($last_id_rows['alias'] === $alias)
    {
        $last_id = $last_id_rows['last_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE text_id > '$last_id'"; //SELECT NEW MESSAGES
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                if ($row['alias'] === "Vether")
                {
                    echo '<p id = "chat_text">'.'<b>'.$row['alias'].'</b>'.': '.$row['text']."</p>";
                    echo '<p id = "time_stamp">'.$row['time'].'</p>';
                    echo '<p id = "chat_number">'.$row['text_id'].'</p>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<p id = "chat_text">'.'<b class = "bold_green">'.$row['alias'].'</b>'.': '.$row['text']."</p>";
                    echo '<p id = "time_stamp">'.$row['time'].'</p>';
                    echo '<p id = "chat_number">'.$row['text_id'].'</p>';
                }
                echo '<hr class = "chat_line"></hr>';
                $last_row_id = $row['text_id'];
            }
        }


        //UPDATE LAST SYNC ID
        $update_query = "UPDATE $last_id_table SET last_id = '$last_row_id' WHERE alias = '$alias'";
        mysqli_query($connection,$update_query);
    }
    else
    {
        $update_query = "INSERT INTO $last_id_table (alias, last_id) VALUES('$alias','-1')";
        mysqli_query($connection,$update_query);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `echo $query` and paste it into Phpmyadmin to verify.

Comment: Another person that is a fan of potential SQL injection

Comment: Try after  removing single quotes from variable $last_id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to this, what do I verify in phpMyAdmin and where? I will edit the quote and try momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

You should change ;

```
WHERE text_id > '$last_id'
```

to

```
WHERE text_id > $last_id
```

`text_id` column is integer and can't be compared like string.

Comment: Alright I tried that -- the comparison completely failed. When text_id = 1 and $last_id  = 0, the conditional did not run.

Comment: "the conditional did not run" would you explain it ? Are you taking error ?

Comment: Also, is your table name "$table" ? Or is it a variable of php ?

Comment: Stuff is echoed into an html div when the conditional runs -- it should run one time, and not run again until there is an incremental offset between text_id and $text_id. $table = 'table_chat_sync';

Comment: To give better perspective, the code is for a chat box, and this is updating the messages for the user. It gets the last appended text_id and compares it to the last_id of messages in the database, if the last_id is greater than the last appended id, then there are new messages, and the conditional would loop through echoing them. So each user has a "last_id" value stored with their unique alias, and its updated each time this code runs (every 3 seconds). With my current code, is just duplicates the last message every 3 seconds.

Comment: Would you try like this ? $query = "SELECT * FROM table_chat_sync WHERE text_id > $last_id"

Comment: It did not work -- I updated the main post with the entire PHP script.

Comment: What exactly did you try in phpmyadmin ? Please share the sql which you tried ? it is the only way to determine the problem sql or php.

Comment: The only debugging I've successfully done in phpMyAdmin is look at both tables at the same time, watching that both id values stay at '1' and watching the code duplicate a chat message every 3 seconds. This means the while loop is running and that the conditional is evaluating to true.

Comment: This is the JS that calls the function: Is it somehow appending the last "data" over and over?
setInterval(function()
{
 $.post("chat_update.php",  function(data) { $("#rect_comments_text").append(data);}  );
}, 3000);